# Getting this info in Console in Eclipse while creating project but project not getting created?

Tags: eclipse, maven

Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.twg.spring
artifactId: mydiary
version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
package: com.twg.spring.mydiary
Y: :

Project not getting created while I am creating a maven project in eclipse. While I am creating it is displaying the above code.

Comment: Maven wants you to type `Y` in the console to confirm the configuration.